# using numpy to read a file into python

Tags: python, numpy, input

So this might be a bit of a noob question as I don't have a whole lot of python experience.  I have a .dat file that I've converted into .csv that I'm trying to read into python.  This should be very simple as numpy has a built in function for this. My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

d = np.loadtxt('scl1.csv', delimiter="\t")
```

The error I get says that it could not convert string to float.  How do I fix this? For reference the data file has 6 columns, where each entry is a number (ie 7.33390715197523163E-002) and they are delimited by tabs.  I thought that the problem could be with the E in some of the numbers but I checked and numpy can read that as a float. Thanks very much for any help.

Edited to include the exact error message if its helpful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Python 3.4/Markov Chain/Monte Carlo.py", line 10, in <module>
    d = np.loadtxt('scl2.dat', delimiter="\t")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 848, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 848, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'   7.33390715197523163E-002  7.68126324487871659E-002  5.46056179421958582E-002  -22.791933511352461        8.7787362443778942       -3.6715272730208461     '
```

Comment: Can you post the first 5 or 6 lines of your file including the header?

Comment: Adding to @GWW's suggestion: make sure the *sample* demonstrates the error when you try to read it with `loadtxt`.

Comment: Try `np.genfromtxt('scl1.csv', delimiter="\t")`. With `loadtext`, make sure your delimiter is correct.

Comment: here are the first 3 lines of data, there is no header. Not sure if the format of the data will display correctly in the commment though

Comment: 7.33390715197523163E-002  7.68126324487871659E-002  5.46056179421958582E-002  -22.791933511352461        8.7787362443778942       -3.6715272730208461     
 -0.11032366115656110       9.61058036106280933E-002 -0.10785545602298079       0.50072238518266166        1.1887691228212711       0.44552227056989957     
  9.03539417380724713E-002  9.67449743610417495E-002  0.19713039272901062        4.4966587161804403       -3.1198608673245660       -7.7887113623899618

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I'm not sure what you mean by making sure the sample demonstrates the error.  Can you explain? thanks

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that the sample would demonstrate the problem.  If the problem occurred at line 100 of the file, and you only included the first 5 lines, we wouldn't be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Are you sure the file is tab separated?  Have you tried using `loadtxt` without the `delimiter` argument?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I could have sworn it was tab separated but taking out the delimiter argument seems to have worked. Thanks very much for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

loadtxt() assumes the file consists only of floats, but your .csv file (likely) has column headings that are strings--hence the conversion error.

If your csv file contains **only** numbers and no quotes, ignore the column names by skipping the first row of the file.

```
np.loadtxt('scl1.csv', delimiter='\t', skiprows=1)
```

Or to grab the headers as well:

```
DELIM = '\t'
fh = open('scl1.csv')
headers = fh.readline().strip().split(DELIM)
data = np.loadtxt(fh, delimiter=DELIM)
```

Otherwise, you could use the csv module and cast the types yourself.

```
read_csv = csv.reader(open('scl1.csv'))
for fields in read_csv:
     pass # process fields list, which are all strings, and includes the col names
```

Also, random tip: don't name things with both an 'l' and a '1' if you can help it!

Comment: The data file has no headers, is only numbers and the occasional E signifying an exponent.  I need to read the data as floats because I will be using numpy to carry out calculations on the first column.  will the csv module you posted work for that? thanks

Comment: Like I said in the answer: csv will return strings. I think you should **try the code for yourself** and see if you can get it to work BEFORE asking "if it will work." That's how we learn.